# Synology Rs812 and WD Red WD60EFRX 6 TB - The volume size must be under 16TB

Tags: hard-drive, nas, disk-space, synology

I'va got a synology Rs812 and 4 x WD Red WD60EFRX 6 TB, now I want those drives in raid-5 or raid-6, but the DSM gives me the message '**The volume size must be under 16TB**'. I'd like to have 24TB..

On the synology website it say's that 6TB drives from western digital are compatible:
https://www.synology.com/en-us/compatibility?search_by=products&category=hdds&p=1&product_bays=4&product_name=RS812&filter_size=6TB

How can I get the 24TB space, well in Raid-5 i should get 18TB right? But in raid-5 it gives me 16TB and I can't click on apply..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The RS812 does not support storage capacity over 16 TB without an expansion enclosure. The following from the Synology RS812 datasheet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So the best thing for me to do is to ask if i can exchange those 6TB drives for 4tb drives because I will not be bying such an expansion?

Comment: @gilko apparently so!